# How to force Regex.Replace to match the '/s' (treat string as single line) regex modifier

Tags: c#, .net, regex

Im working with a Regex to get the a string between two strings in a HTML. In the

[Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/qM0jI6/1) its worrking as expected. But in the .NET it not wrapping the string that i want. Heres the code:

```
html = Regex.Replace(html, @"(?<=<strong>CNPJ:)(.*?)(?=hddServidorCaptcha)\s*", string.Empty);
```

The only difference is that i specified the `/s` on the site. But the default in .NET is `/g` .Is there a way to change it? 
Thanks

Comment: You should specify what `/g` and `/s` means so that it is easier for people who know the .NET types to answer.

Comment: `/g` is global, `/s` is single line.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use an [overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/taz3ak2f.aspx) of that same method:

```
html = Regex.Replace(html, @"(?<=<strong>CNPJ:)(.*?)(?=hddServidorCaptcha)\s*", string.Empty, RegexOptions.SingleLine);
```

Answer (score 3):

Do not confuse the `g` (global) modifier with the `s` (Singleline) **aka** (*dotall*) modifier.

The `g` (global) modifier meaning all matches (don't return on first match) does not exist, that is why you would use the [`Regex.Matches()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.matches.aspx) method if you were returning multiple match results.

The `s` (*dotall*) modifier, allows the dot `.` to span across newline sequences. By default, the dot `.` doesn't match newline sequences. You can simply use the [`(?s)`](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-modifiers.html#dotall) inline modifier here:

```
@"(?s)(?<=<strong>CNPJ:)(.*?)(?=hddServidorCaptcha)"

  ^^^^
```